# How to store comma separated argument using scanner

Tags: java

I am taking user input using scanner and want to store 2 argument given from command line how ever I am only able to get one.
Also I believe hasNextInt() returns boolean value if there is a nextInt, however when I enter a non-int value it doesnot break the loop.

I have checked sources online and on stackoverflow before posting this questions but did not get what I was looking for.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

int first = 0;
int second = 0;
System.out.println("Please enter number: ");
s.useDelimiter(",");
while (s.hasNextInt()) {
    first = s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("firstArgument: " + first + "\n");
    second = s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("secondArgument: " + second + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you post some sample input/output as well as the intended output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code calls `s.hasNextInt()` for every odd-numbered input, but it tries to take each even-numbered input without performing a check. Therefore, it requires inputs like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,done
1,2,3,4,done
1,2,done
```

However, inputs like this would result in an exception:

```
1,2,3,4,5,done
1,2,3,done
1,done
```

Note that a non-numeric input must appear after a comma on the same line.

To fix this problem, add a check before reading the second value:

```
while (s.hasNextInt()) {
    first = s.nextInt();
    if (!s.hasNextInt()) break'
    second = s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("firstArgument: " + first + "\n");
    System.out.print("secondArgument: " + second + "\n");
}
```

If you would like to allow other characters, such as end-of-line markers, to end your comma-separated list, use a different expression for delimiters:

```
s.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
```

Comment: I tried doing that but that does not get the second argument still. I believe the break breaks out of the loop.

Comment: @Mani Yes, `break` breaks out of the loop when there is no further valid input.

Comment: so how does this achieve storing both the inputs. 
eg I enter `1,2` I want the `first = 1` and `second = 2` . with the break I get only `first` and I can do that without the break as well.

Comment: @Mani That's because there is no "wrong" input after the comma. This is addressed by the second part of the answer (i.e. the delimiter). Note that the loop would stop only when you enter a non-empty string that is not a number following the numeric comma-separated input.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. That does store both the argument and ends with a non-int value